# I need to pass a parameter expected by a . tag file, using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a .tag file that renders an HTML output but it expects an attribute. I need to pass the required data to that tag file using a javascript file. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.tag files are just Servlets (they run on the server) so the only way you have to pass values from JS to the .tag is launching a request with those values on it to the jsp that includes the .tag and access them via the Request object like: `${requestScope.myParam}`

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. I wish it was that easy. You probably want to pass a client property to the tag (which reside on de server) but that's not going to work..